# queryStarting(atValue not working as intended?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am wondering how I could use firebase ordering queries to make pagination work in my app.

So I have tried the following:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row == postArray.count - 1 {
        //we are at last cell load more content
        //Do some logic here I think like
        limit += 10
         getRecentPosts(limit)
        //self.perform(#selector(reloadData), with: nil, afterDelay: 1.0)
    }
}

@objc func reloadData() {
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

And:
 I do this for it to work. But It does not, I expand on this below.

```
  ref.child("Timeline").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!)
  .queryStarting(atValue: "\(postArray[postArray.count-1].user.userID!):\(postArray[postArray.count-1].media[0].postID!)")//here is a sample val: KVDB2sNMgUN90tpkmQKfjrroOmt1:post:580367065
  .queryLimited(toLast: UInt(limit)).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

My fetch fucntion looks like this:

```
        } else {
        print("ffdsafsfsdfasdfsd?????", postArray.count)
        print("\(postArray[postArray.count-1].user.userID!):\(postArray[postArray.count-1].media[0].postID!)", "  fhdskagfakshgfjdshflkahflkjashlkjfhslkj")

        ref.child("Timeline").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!)
            .queryStarting(atValue: "\(postArray[postArray.count-1].user.userID!):\(postArray[postArray.count-1].media[0].postID!)")
            .queryLimited(toLast: UInt(limit)).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                print("resulst here?????????")
                if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                    print(snapshots, " this is the snapshot of the people you follow", snapshots.count)

                    for child in snapshots.reversed() {

                        let keyValue = child.key
                        let uid = keyValue.split(separator: ":")[0]
                        let postIDDoubleVal = keyValue.split(separator: ":")[2]


                        self.fetchUsersPost(uid: String(uid), postID: "post:\(postIDDoubleVal)")
                    }
                }
            })
    }
}
```

### Update:

I have found that the logic works as needed but that inside the place where i print :

```
                    if let snapshots = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {
                    print(snapshots, " this is the snapshot of the people you follow", snapshots.count)
```

I get the following output:

```
[]  this is the snapshot of the people you follow 0
```

**Why is this?** i checked the DB for the starting point I gave it and it does exist

Comment: You seem to be missing one of the required functions for doing a query; `queryOrdered(by` as shown in the Firebase Documentation [Sorting & Filtering Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data)'

Comment: Where does it say that is a required method? I have been querying for a long time never using that. @Jay

Comment: Firebase needs to know what child you are querying on. The docs state *To retrieve sorted data, **start by specifying** one of the **order-by** methods to determine how results are ordered:* The code is a bit hard to decipher but it looks like your path is /Timeline/some_uid but the queryStarting:at is starting at `KVDB2sNMgUN90tpkmQKfjrroOmt1:post:580367065`. It's a little unclear what you're trying to do there - either way though, it needs to know what node your trying to reference; it could the the key with `.queryOrderedByKey` or it could be a value with `queryOrderedByValue`

Comment: *note it can be omitted if you are using the natural key ordering, but then I don't believe you can define a starting point. i.e. if there's 100 posts, you can return the last 3 (most recent) with .queryLimited(toLast: 3)

Comment: Ok @Jay, given this I believe I dont know how queryStarting:at works. I am trying to make pagination work, and so I thought that I could make it work by, when the user gets to the last cell, fetch posts from the last postRef to the next 10+. Does queryStarting:at not work by allowing me to specify essentially => [starting at the index of this string fetch the next 10]

Comment: Well, Firebase doesn't have a buit in index so you have to know how to order the data and then where to start to load the data. You could do that by the key of your nodes or by the value of a child within the node. Take a look at my answer and see if it clarifies it. It get's tricky; suppose you have posts that can be voted on and you want to display them 10 at a time in order of votes. That's a great use case of orderBy: number_of_votes and limitTo(10). Because the posts could appear in any order in the database and you want them to be returned by number of votes, so a 'key' order won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand the query in the question so let's see if we can produce an answer via an example.

Let's take a structure of posts

```
Timeline
   uid_0
      post_0: "a"
      post_1: "b"
      post_2: "c"
      post_3: "d"
      post_4: "e"
      post_5: "f"
      post_6: "g"
      post_7: "h"
      post_8: "i"
      post_9: "j"
```

There are multiple ways this can be paginated but let's use two simple examples.

In this first example, suppose we want three posts starting at post_3, so we want d, e and f, and we know the actual key to start with, post_3.

```
func paginationByKey() {
    let ref = self.ref.child("Timeline").child("uid_0")
    let q0 = ref.queryOrderedByKey() //they will be ordered by key
    let q1 = q0.queryStarting(atValue: "post_3").queryLimited(toFirst: 3)
    q1.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot)
    })
}
```

this will return

```
Snap (uid_0) {
    "post_3" = d;
    "post_4" = e;
    "post_5" = f;
}
```

In this second example, in many cases the node keys are generated with a push() or .childByAutoId so you won't know the key. However, you would know the starting value, like a date or timestamp for example. Also, the data could really be stored in any order in the database. To handle that we know the first value we want to read in is 'd' followed by 'e' and 'f'

```
func paginationByValue() {
    let ref = self.ref.child("Timeline").child("uid_0")
    let q0 = ref.queryOrderedByValue() //ordering the data by child value
    let q1 = q0.queryStarting(atValue: "d").queryLimited(toFirst: 3)
    q1.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        print(snapshot)
    })
}
```

and the output is

```
Snap (uid_0) {
    "post_3" = d;
    "post_4" = e;
    "post_5" = f;
}
```

To paginate, since you know the last node loaded had a value of 'f', the next set of data would start with 'g'. There are a couple of ways to handle that:

One way is to actually load in 4 nodes and display 3. The 4th node is the starting point for the next set of data, so you would perhaps keep that in a class var for reference.

Another option is to start the query at the last node of the set of nodes just loaded, 'f' in this case' but throw out the first one (which will be 'f') of the new set as it was already in the prior set.